# NavigationLink on SwiftUI pushes view twice

Tags: ios, swiftui

When adding a NavigationLink in SwiftUI the destination is presented twice, ex: I tap on the NavigationLink and it pushes my destination but when I dismiss the destination, via the back button or the swipe gesture it pushes the destination again without taping on the link. 
Here is the part of my code that handles the link:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 8.0) {
        ForEach(part.getReference()) { (imageRef: ReferenceImage) in
            ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                Image(uiImage: imageRef.getUIImage())
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                .cornerRadius(6)
                .onLongPressGesture {
                    print("looong")
                    self.managedObjectContext.delete(imageRef)
                    do {
                        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        print("error deleting: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.appColors.lightRose)
                        .opacity(0.7)
                        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                    Image(systemName: "arkit")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                }
                NavigationLink(destination:
                    ZStack {
                        Color.appColors.rose
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                        ReferenceARSwiftUIView(currentImage: imageRef.getUIImage())
                            .navigationBarTitle("AR Reference")
                    }

                ) {
                    EmptyView()
                    .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                }

            }
        }.animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 0.5, damping: 0.5))
```

**EDIT 01:**
As suggested I removed a bit of the noise in the code:

```
var part: Part
var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 8.0) {
        ForEach(part.getReference()) { (imageRef: ReferenceImage) in
            ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                Image(uiImage: imageRef.getUIImage())
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                .cornerRadius(6)
                NavigationLink(destination: ReferenceARSwiftUIView(currentImage: imageRef.getUIImage())) {
                    EmptyView()
                    .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                }

            }
        }.animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 0.5, damping: 0.5))
```

**EDIT 02:**
I think I narrowed down, basically if I remove the ForEach the NavigationLink pushes correctly to the next View. Also depending on the number of itens I have on my array for the ForEach the number of pushes is the same.

Comment: Any chance you could strip out and/or add things to your code for us to duplicate your issue? You have several things (`Color.appColors.lightRose`, `Image`, unneeded stacks) that really add noise. Maybe if you strip it down to `NavigationView`, `NavigationLink`, and *maybe* the `ForEach` to have us duplicate your issue, you might find it's working... and at that point you can add back in the rest to see why the code you posted isn't.

Comment: Okay a have removed most of the noise from the code, I think 

Comment: I may have narrowed down the problem, I explained on the edit 02

Comment: Thanks, hope I didn't offend you. Two thoughts. (1) I rarely see a `ForEach` without a `List`. Would this help? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach More, (2) I actively check this site for the SwiftUI tag. I recall several questions with regards to both `List` nd `NavigationLink` (even `Button`) behavior in loops. Have you searched this site for those? Truth is, I stopped using the combination of `NavigationView` and `List` because of how... raw... SwiftUI is compared to UIKit,

Comment: why dont you put the whole ZStack in the NavigationLink? and then you can get rid of the emptyview

Comment: @yawnobleix if I do that each one of the images has a arrow attached

Comment: I had the same issue. I believe there may be a bug in SwiftUI when using NavigationLink within ForEach. I could not get it to work with `ScrollView` as suggested below. I am only able to get it working if I don't use ForEach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by setting the NavigationLink's tag to the unique id of the model item.

Assuming you have an id for your imageRef, ReferenceImage class.

```
var part: Part
var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 8.0) {
        ForEach(part.getReference()) { (imageRef: ReferenceImage) in
            ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                Image(uiImage: imageRef.getUIImage())
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                .cornerRadius(6)
                NavigationLink(destination: ReferenceARSwiftUIView(currentImage: imageRef.getUIImage()), tag: imageRef.id) {
                    EmptyView()
                    .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                }

            }
        }.animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 0.5, damping: 0.5))
```

```
NavigationLink(destination: ReferenceARSwiftUIView(currentImage: imageRef.getUIImage()), tag: imageRef.id)
```

Comment: I am getting this issue even without ListView

Answer (score 11):

I'm sure that `Part` conforms to `Identifiable` protocol and has `id` property.

The destination of the `NavigationLink` is presented multiple times because you have multiple instances of `Part` that have the exact same identity `id` in the `forEach` loop.

Just make sure that each instance of `Part` has a unique `id` and everything will work as expected.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/working-with-identifiable-items-in-swiftui

Answer (score 1):

Yeah changing `List` to `ScrollView` helped me in a similar situation.

```
ScrollView {
    if !usersViewModel.isLoading {
        ForEach(self.usersViewModel.users, id: \.id) { user in
            NavigationLink(destination: UserDashboardView(showDashboardDetail: $showDashboardDetail, user: user)) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    NetworkCardView(user: user)
                }
                .frame(width: screen.size.width - 60, height: 250)
                .padding(.top)
            }
        }
        .listRowBackground(AppColor())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your issue, because even the stripped down version contains types declared by you, but not included in the question.

A couple of things:

If you want to use `NavigationLink`, the view needs to be embeded in a `NavigationView`.

If you are using `ForEach` inside an `HStack` there is a chance you are going to run out of space to display all the elements, so it would be a good idea to wrap it in a `ScrollView`.

Last, but not least: inside `ForEach` you have to make `NavigationLink` your top level view and make any other views its content:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
           ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(part.getReference()) { (imageRef: ReferenceImage) in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ReferenceARSwiftUIView(currentImage: imageRef.getUIImage())) {
                            Image(uiImage: imageRef.getUIImage())
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                                .cornerRadius(6)
                        }
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    }
```