# NavigationLink Pushes View Multiple Times Before Returning To Parent View

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

### The Problem

I have 3 views: ListView --> WorkoutView --> EditStepView.

When I start in ListView, then navigate to WorkoutView, and finally tap the NavigationLink to EditStepView, EditStepView pushes a few times and quickly returns to the relative safety of WorkoutView. Why is this happening?

[Click here to see a gif of the error](https://twitter.com/workbytaylor/status/1416948792268558338?s=20)

### What I've Tried

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946197/navigationlink-on-swiftui-pushes-view-twice) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696286/swiftui-list-elements-within-nested-array), with no luck so far. Though I think the first could be on to something.

I've noticed that the error goes away if I have only 2 strings saved in steps (see data model). As soon as I add a third string to steps, the error occurs.

My suspicion is that ForEach cannot identify which string it is tied to, and so I need to find a way to id each string or change the data model (I don't yet know how to do this).

**Thanks for your time!**

---

#### ListView

```
struct ListView: View {
    var workouts: [WorkoutData]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(workouts) { workout in
                NavigationLink(destination: WorkoutView(workout: workout)) {
                    WorkoutCardView(workout: workout)
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

#### WorkoutView

```
struct WorkoutView: View {
    var workout: WorkoutData
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(workout.steps, id: \.self) { workout in
                NavigationLink(destination: EditStepView()) {
                    Text(workout)
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

#### EditStepView

```
struct EditStepView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            // A form, does not yet accept data
        }
        .navigationTitle("Edit Step")
    }
}
```

#### WorkoutData (data model)

```
struct WorkoutData: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var title: String
    var steps: [String]   //an array containing a string

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), title: String, steps: [String]) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.steps = steps
    }
}

extension WorkoutData {
    static var data: [WorkoutData] {
        [   WorkoutData(title: "2 On 3 Off", steps: [  
                                   //    Test data
                                                   "Run hard for 2 minutes",
                                                   "Jog for 3 minutes",
                                                   "Run hard for 2 minutes",
                                                   "Jog for 3 minutes",
                                                   "Run hard for 2 minutes",
                                                   "Jog for 3 minutes",
                                                ]),
            WorkoutData(title: "10 x 400m", steps: [""]),
            WorkoutData(title: "4-1 Ladder", steps: [""]),
            WorkoutData(title: "5 Minute Repeats", steps: [""]),
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: works well on ios15. You could try this (add the id) in your ListView, "ForEach(workouts, id: \.id) { workout in

Answer (score 0):

Solved Issue

Model

```
struct WorkoutData: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var title: String
    var steps: [Steps]   //an array containing a string
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), title: String, steps: [Steps]) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.steps = steps
    }
}

struct Steps: Identifiable  {
    var id: UUID
    var step : String
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), step: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.step = step
    }
}

extension WorkoutData {
    static var data: [WorkoutData] {
        [WorkoutData(title: "2 On 3 Off", steps: [.init(step: "Run hard for 2 minutes"),.init(step: "Jog for 3 minutes"),.init(step: "Run hard for 2 minutes"),.init(step: "Jog for 3 minutes"),.init(step: "Run hard for 2 minutes"),.init(step: "Jog for 3 minutes")]),
         WorkoutData(title: "10 x 400m", steps: [.init(step: "")]),
         WorkoutData(title: "4-1 Ladder", steps: [.init(step: "")]),
         WorkoutData(title: "5 Minute Repeats", steps: [.init(step: "")])]
    }
}
```

ListView

```
struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List {
                ForEach(WorkoutData.data, id: \.id) { workout in
                    NavigationLink(destination: WorkoutView(workout: workout)) {
                        WorkoutCardView(workout: workout)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

WorkoutView

```
struct WorkoutView: View {
    var workout: WorkoutData
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(workout.steps, id: \.id) { workout in
                NavigationLink(destination: EditStepView()) {
                    Text(workout.step)
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

EditStepView

```
struct EditStepView: View {
    var body: some View {
           Form {
               // A form, does not yet accept data
           }
           .navigationTitle("Edit Step")
       }
}
```